# In MapReduce, why does the map function output 1 when finding word occurrence?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, large-data

Let's say I want to find how many times each word appears inside some text.

My understanding was that the text is separated into sections, and each section is passed to `map`. `map` would then get the word occurrences for each section and pass the result to `reduce`, like this:

```
for each word w in document:
    occurrences[w] += 1

return occurrences
```

However, according to the [MapReduce paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Examples), `map` would simply emit 1 for each word, like this:

```
for each word w in document:
    emit(w, 1)
```

Isn't this basically just the same thing as passing the text section to `reduce` directly since it's gonna have to iterate through each word anyways?

Also, just to make sure. If I want to sort a large array with MapReduce, would `map` sort it's part of the array, and then `reduce` would merge the sorted arrays, like in mergesort?

Answer (score 1):

Just to review how map-reduce works:

In the word count example that you cited, the map reads the split/section as you mentioned.

While scanning through the section of words, the map doesn't perform the occurrence count,
what the map is doing is creating a key-value pair of `<"word",1>`. This simplifies the downstream aggregation of the words by the reducer.

The map is doing that so that the reducer which handles that handles that particular `"word"` could collect all the `<"word",1>` tuples sent its way and then generate the count by adding all the 1s together.

In short, lets say you have a list of words as follows:

```
cat
rat
mat
bat
cat
sat
bat
```

Lets say we have 3 mappers that handle the file split as follows:

Split1 for mapper1:

```
cat
rat
mat
```

Split2 for mapper2:

```
bat
cat
```

Split3 for mapper3:

```
sat
bat
```

The mapper1 will emit:

```
<cat,1>
<rat,1>
<mat,1>
```

Mapper2 will emit:

```
<bat,1>
<cat,1>
```

Mapper3 will emit:

```
<sat,1>
<bat,1>
```

Although the reality is a little more complex but ideally, you have one reducer for each word and they receive the tuples from each of the mappers.

```
So reducer for cat receives:<cat,1> , <cat,1>
The reducer for rat receives: <rat,1>
The reducer for mat receives: <mat,1>
The reducer for bat receives: <bat,1>,<bat,1>
The reducer for sat receives: <sat,1>
```

Each of the reducer adds up all the tuples that it has received and gets an aggregate value as follows:

```
<cat,2>
<rat,1>
<mat,1>
<bat,2>
<sat,1>
```

That's how map-reduce implements the word-count. The idea is to parallelize the count operation.

As far as your question about sorting goes, it is more of a "bucketing" trick than a "merge". The map-reduce framework would internally sort the data and stream it to the reducer in sorted order.

Please check this [post](http://grepalex.com/2012/09/10/sorting-text-files-with-mapreduce/) for more details.

Comment: Hey, let's say split1 contained `cat`, `cat`, `mat`. Why wouldn't I configure map to emit `<cat, 2>`, `<mat, 1>` rather than `<cat, 1>`, `<cat, 1>`,  `<mat, 1>`? Thanks

Comment: @mzee99 - You can. But that would require your map to hold on to state for each of your words. Combiners(https://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Custom+combiner) are typically used to perform the step that you mentioned.

Comment: Is there any difference in terms of efficiency one way or the other?

Comment: Use same class for Combiner & Reducer

Comment: Why not just emit the word? I was thinking there is a lot of overhead to store an integer for every single word ...

Answer (score 0):

If you Mapper want to do **Reducer** job by emitting , use Combiner, which is semi reducer. Combiner works on output of Mapper and does a reducer job Here.

If you implement **Customer Partitioner**, Shuffler and Reducer : It will be more effective.

**Partitioner** will make sure that reducers are load balanced.

**Shuffle** will make sure that a particular key form Mapper is emitted to a particular reducer.

**Combiner** will do mini reducer job and combined output of Mapper.

**Sorting** will sort all values of Mapper output before reaching Reducer.

In Combiner cases, most of the times Combiner & Reducer classes will be set as same classes.

Even with combiner, the output will be w,[1,1] instead of w,[ 2]

```
//Set Combiner class as WordcounReducer class.
job.setCombinerClass(WordcountReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(WordcountReducer.class);
```

Have a look at detailed [example](http://hadooptutorial.info/combiner-in-mapreduce/) and this [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141631/what-is-the-purpose-of-shuffling-and-sorting-phase-in-the-reducer-in-map-reduce/33395854#33395854) and this one [SE Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406566/combiner-inplementation-and-internal-working/33408776#33408776)